# Why does C++20 not support "void f(Concept const auto&)"?

Tags: c++, templates, standards, c++20, c++-concepts

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>
concept HasSize = requires(T obj)
{
    obj.size();    
};

void f1(HasSize auto arg) {} // ok
void f2(HasSize auto&& arg) {} // ok
void f3(HasSize decltype(auto) arg) {} // ok
void f4(HasSize auto& arg) {}  // ok
void f5(HasSize auto* arg) {}  // ok

void f6(HasSize const auto& arg) {} // error

int main()
{
    std::string str{};

    f1(std::string{});
    f2(std::string{});
    f3(std::string{});
    f4(str);
    f5(&str);
    f6(str);
}
```

Compiled with `clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ z.cpp` and the error messages are:

```
z.cpp:15:6: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
void f6(HasSize const auto& arg) {} // error
     ^
z.cpp:15:9: error: too few template arguments for concept 'HasSize'
void f6(HasSize const auto& arg) {} // error
        ^
z.cpp:4:9: note: template is declared here
concept HasSize = requires(T obj)
        ^
z.cpp:15:33: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
void f6(HasSize const auto& arg) {} // error
                                ^
                                ;
3 errors generated.
```

**Why does C++20 not support "void f(Concept const auto&)"?**

Comment: Don't know if it answers your question, but `auto const&` seems to work. Also gcc does not like [HasSize decltype(auto) arg](https://wandbox.org/permlink/683fwM3NR40P8JiX). What would that even mean in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong.

*type-constraints*, such as the concept `HasSize` here, belong directly before the *placeholder-type-specifier*, i.e. before `auto` or `decltype(auto)`:

```
void f6(const HasSize auto& arg) {}
```

See [[dcl.spec.auto]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.dcl#dcl.spec.auto) of the C++20 draft.

The *cv-qualifier*s, such as `const`, are separate from the *placeholder-type-specifier*s, see [[decl.type]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.dcl#nt:type-specifier).

---

As mentioned by @super in a question comment `decltype(auto)` is not allowed in a function parameter. So this seems to be a Clang bug to accept it, see [[dcl.spec.auto]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.dcl#dcl.spec.auto-2) which only allows the *auto* case for a *placeholder-type-specifier* in a function parameter.

Answer (score 9):

The concept name must appear right before `auto`. Either:

```
void f(const Concept auto&)
```

or:

```
void f(Concept auto const&)
```

are both valid.

The motivation was ([P1141](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1141r2.html)):

> To keep things simple, an `auto` (or `decltype(auto)`) being constrained is always immediately preceded by the constraint.